# Are we being graduated?

Tags: discussion, graduation, design

Hmmm...

Or are we just getting the site design update we were promised where we told the SE folks, sure, we'd love a site update but it's not enough: we want full graduation.

Even if it's just the update, that's a good thing.

**Where do we stand?**

[image]

Comment: Wait.  It says "big changes for Y2K" (I thought at first it said "big changes for YOU") and uses Comic Sans.  Maybe it's not an update but a degeneration.  Anyone know?

Comment: Not to mention the (ominous?):"Just like the '90s, good things have to come to an end. If you want to switch to the current site, you'll find the option here."

Comment: @NofP Yeah, at first I thought it was just a joke about the 90's but then I saw the rest.  Of course, this might be the design template (HNQ has actual flame gifs, help me God!) and the intermediary stage before they make changes.

Comment: Oh crud.  It's an error.  Worldbuilding has the same problem.

Comment: is maybe April's fools happening early this year?

Comment: @NofP That seems to be it

Answer (score 5):

<s>It appears to be a glitch.</s>  **It's an April Fools Joke**

Worldbuilding (which graduated a long time ago) has the same half-finished 1999 design.

To make it go away, click the clock icon on the top right of every page that has it.  You usually have to click it twice.  Then you get a page with ordinary formatting.

Looking on META.  It appears to be an early April Fools joke.
[What testing is done on 'April Fool' pranks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326014/what-testing-is-done-on-april-fool-pranks)

Answer (score 3):

I first checked https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writers  and it showed only 8 Qs/day, so I worried that we were being demoted down to 1990/myspace layout!

Comment: ha ha that would be a horrible punishment.